# Nginx Very slow if i use proxy pass in HTTPS via reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i've implemented a Reverse proxy with nginx but i've a problem, when i connect into my device via reverse proxy the device is very slow, i've tried to set the keepalive but the problem persists, the only solution is to use the protocol http in proxy pass but is not a good idea.

This is my configuration:

```
location /rp/@testdevice@/ {
auth_request /_autentication_test/21222;
error_page 401 /40x.html;

resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
set $upstream_rp_21222 x.x.x.x;
proxy_pass https://$upstream_rp_21222;

#proxy_pass https://x.x.x.x/;
rewrite ^/rp/@testdevice@/(.*)$ /$1 break;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
proxy_ssl_verify off;
proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /rp/@testdevice@/;
subs_filter_types *;
subs_filter "http://x.x.x.x/test/" "//@testdevice@/test/";
subs_filter "https://x.x.x.x:8443/" "/rp/@testdevice@/";
subs_filter "https://x.x.x.x:443/" "/rp/@testdevice@/";
subs_filter "https://x.x.x.x/" "/rp/@testdevice@/";
}


upstream xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx_443 {
server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 resolve;
keepalive 15;
keepalive_timeout 10s;
}
```

The nginx version is 1.25.3

Please help me :(

i've tried to set the keepalive but the problem persists

i've tried to set the keepalive but the problem persists

Comment: `when i connect into my device via reverse proxy the device is very slow` Means what? What device, what is "slow"? You are aware that HTTPS use cryptographic which use a lot of CPU, right?

Comment: proxy_pass https://$upstream_rp_21222 inside this link is present a router administrative page, i need to use reverse proxy to connect in this router, but the page is very slow in reverse proxy when i use https, i've checked the cpu but i don't see load...